# WAMP Server 2.1: Change default text editor

Tags: windows

I want to use Notepad++ to open my httpd.conf and php.ini configuration files and have associated those file types in Windows to Notepad++; opening those documents via windows opens Notepad++. But when I use WAMP (Apache MySQL and PHP for windows) Server's menu to access these config files it opens Microsoft Notepad, an unacceptable editor. Is there any known way to change how WAMP Server opens these files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look for the [apacheMenu] section of your `wampmanager.tpl` file. There are definitions in that file that specify how to edit various configuration files including what editor to use.

To set NP++ as the default for all the files you can do a simple find-and-replace of `"notepad.exe"` --> `"C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"` - note the forward slashes instead of backslashes.

> Note that in new WAMP version there is a wampmanager.conf file which contains all the variables' definitions therefore you should change the "editor" constant there instead of directly modifying the .tpl file –  Milan Jan 20 2015 (This comment was auto-hidden, but 100% relevant, and where you need to edit it in the newer WAMP)

Comment: Technically the wampmanager.tpl file has to be edited, the .ini is regenerated every time WAMP starts from that file. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I made the changes, stopped WampServer from the command line with "wampmanager.exe -quit -id={wampserver}" and restarted it with "wampmanager.exe", but it still uses notepad.

Comment: wampmanager.ini is automatically created when I restart wampmanager, and it contains "notepad.exe" even though I chagned wampmanager.tpl

Comment: In new Wamp versions - I tested only Version 2.5 - there is new approach in wampmanager.tpl it is defining the variable `${c_editor}` with your favorite editor path in the beginning of the tpl file something like the following: `${c_editor} = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe";`

Comment: in wampmanager.conf, use editor = "C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"

Comment: Note that in new WAMP version there is a wampmanager.conf file which contains all the variables' definitions therefore you should change the "editor" constant there instead of directly modifying the .tpl file